# How do I change an image using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I expect my code to change the image.

I've made sure the script tag is correct.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("card_1_img");
x.src = "images/1.png"; //the error occurs here
```

```html
<img id="card_1_img" width="100" height="50">
```

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is most likely running before your HTML loads. Try putting your `<script>` tag at the bottom of the page, before your closing `</body>`:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("card_1_img");
x.src = "images/1.png";
```

```html
<body>
  <img id="card_1_img" width="100" height="50">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: You could also place the script tag in the head with the attribute "defer" as long as you are using an external script.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what issue, i reproduce it.

May be you put script tag in head tag and img tag did not created.

```js
 var x = document.getElementById("card_1_img");
    x.src = "https://hinhanhdephd.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/hinh-anh-dep-girl-xinh-hinh-nen-dep-gai-xinh.jpg";
```

```html
<img id="card_1_img" width="100" height="50">
```

Answer (score -1):

#### Live example switching images:

```js
let chromeImg = "https://www.w3schools.com/images/compatible_chrome.gif";
let firefoxImg = "https://www.w3schools.com/images/compatible_firefox.gif";

function change(browser) {
  let img = document.getElementById("browser");
  let name = document.getElementById("name");
  if (browser.src.includes("chrome")) {
    img.src = firefoxImg;
    name.textContent = "FireFox";
  } else {
    img.src = chromeImg;
    name.textContent = "Chrome";
  }
}
```

```css
img, p {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<h5>Click on image below:</h5>
<img id="browser" onclick="change(this)" 
     src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/compatible_chrome.gif">
<p id="name"></p>
```

---

#### Reference:

- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_src.asp